# Will the ubuntu 16.4.2 LTS installer be able to automatically configure the bootloader on a win 10 laptop?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, uefi

I have a win 10 laptop. I have somehow managed to boot Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS from a live usb, although I have to do it manually `(Switch on computer and press esc repeatedly->boot options->select EFI file->select usb drive->EFI->BOOT->boot64.efi)`. For some reason my Live USB is not detected as a bootable device automatically. The persistant file isnt working for some reason. :( Even the wifi isnt working in live mode.

Anyway, Ubuntu loads in the Live Mode. I want to dual boot it with Windows 10. If I start the installer, will it be able to configure the bootloader properly? Or will I have to modify the settings manually? I saw some online tutorials which said you have to use something called `efibootmgr`... Can't it be done without that tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah `grub` and `os-prober` makes real dualbooting with Windows, so don't worry about that... you dont have to configure nothing.

Is completely normal that you computer don't want to boot the USB automatically because that option is disabled by default in the BIOS, just make sure to free a bit of your hard drive space from Windows Disk Manager utility. And when you do that, reboot the computer and the Wubi installer will do his magic selecting the option "install Ubuntu alongside Windows".

Here's an example
Boot Windows

Press <kbd>⊞</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and select "Disk Manager"

Select the most large partition, and then right-click in Shrink Volume
[image: disk manager]

Now the math part, the ammount of space that you want for Ubuntu, multiply * 1024, for me I just want 64 GB so that is 64 GB * 1024 = 65536 MB

So I will enter 65536 for shrink

[image: shrink]

and then you will see a black square. Just don't touch that, we don't want to assign any filesystem. Also the Installer will recognize that ammount of space, for automatically install Ubuntu.

[image: black]

And that's how to shrink space from Windows, once you do that just select the first option when installing from Live Session, "Install alongside Windows 10" and make sure to disable "secure boot" option in the BIOS because that thing is a pain in the ass for multiboot.

[image: ubuntu]

Hope this helps,

For booting the USB try <kbd>F12</kbd> / <kbd>F11</kbd> / <kbd>F9</kbd> keys.
For entering BIOS press <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>DEL</kbd> / <kbd>SUPR</kbd> keys.

PS.Sorry for the pictures in spanish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will tell you if it worked later when I install ubuntu.

Comment: This is generally good advice, although there are special cases when something more may be required. Those are just that, though -- *special* cases, and best dealt with as such. Note that disabling Secure Boot falls in this category, at least partially -- Ubuntu *usually* works fine with Secure Boot enabled. Disabling it is required in case of some buggy EFIs, complex setups, etc. If you use third-party drivers (most commonly for ATI or Nvidia video or VirtualBox), Secure Boot adds complications, too. I'd try with Secure Boot enabled and disable it only if problems ensue.

Comment: And the installer is NOT Wubi. Wubi *was* an 'hack' to enable "installing" Ubuntu *inside* Windows like any Windows software, hence the `wubi.exe`, and working more or less like a virtual machine. Also, no longer developed or supported, doesn't even install in any Windows 8 or newer, already removed from recent ISOs and shouldn't be mentioned. Your answer is correct except this small but misleading detail.